# PloneFormGen Header Injection Example

Tags: plone, zope, ploneformgen

PloneFormGen allows to inject custom data into the web page header with so-called *Header Injection*. the description is:

> This override field allows you to insert content into the xhtml head.
>   The typical use is to add custom CSS or JavaScript. Specify a TALES
>   expression returning a string. The string will be inserted with no
>   interpretation. PLEASE NOTE: errors in the evaluation of this
>   expression will cause an error on form display.

i wonder what is proper syntax of such expression.. i did not succeed with following example

```
<style type="text/css"> * { color: red !important; } </style>
```

neither with

```
<style tal:attributes="type:text/css" tal:content="* { color: red !important; }">
```

neither with

```
<style tal:attributes="type:text/css" tal:content="string:* { color: red !important; }">
```

neither with

```
<style tal:attributes="type string:text/css" tal:content="string: * { color: red !important; }" />
```

the error message informs me only that it *has errors*..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field is interpreted as a TALES expression; the results of that expression are what will be inserted. None of your examples are TALES expressions; the last 3 each do *use* TALES expressions as part of a larger TAL template statement though.

In your case, all you need is a `string:` expression to return a static result:

```
string:<style type="text/css"> * { color: red !important; } </style>
```

Comment: Also, see an example of injecting a whole file at http://plone.org/products/ploneformgen/documentation/how-to/restyle-a-form

Comment: Steve,  That link appears to be broken.  Can you point it to the new location of that example?

Comment: @JoeBigler: see http://docs.plone.org/working-with-content/managing-content/ploneformgen/restyle.html#an-alternative-way-to-inject-css